# Why does lspci lists pcie devices?

Tags: linux, pci, pci-e

When I do `lspci` I can see my nvme ssds. Why is that? Aren't PCI buses supposed to be separate from PCIe buses?

Comment: Probably should be asked in [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com).

Comment: They didn't want to create a separate `lspcie` utility when pcie came along - (and in many architectures, there's  just one controller for both pci and pcie)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming and is better suited at e..g  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the hardware, PCI busses and PCIe busses are separate, but PCIe was specifically designed to be software compatible with PCI, so in fact it would be surprising if lspci didn't work seamlessly with PCIe.